# Override "readonly" attribute of a field in one2many relation

Tags: xml, odoo

Let's suppose the following code :

```
<field name="object_ids" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', 'not in', ['A', 'B'])]}">
    <form string="My object" version="7.0">
        <field name="object_name"/>
        <field name="object_description"/>
    </form>
</field>
```

This is an example, just to illustrate a definition of a form view for a one2many field.

Is there a way to override the `readonly` attribute set in the `object_ids` child fields (`object_name`) ?

In this case, my whole form view will be readonly for the states specified, but I would like to bypass / override this attribute for a specific field. For example :

```
...
<field name="object_name" attrs="{'readonly': False}"> <!-- overrides the readonly set -->
...
```

Is there a way to do this ? Or do I have to remove the attribute from the `one2many` field and add it to each field ? The goal here is to avoid having this attribute repeated for each field (time consuming, error prone because of inherits of views).

Comment: No you cannot do it, if the field is read only you cannot edit it's lines

Comment: That's sad .. Post your comment as an answer so I can mark it, thanks for your input.

Comment: You can try make readonly true the one2many field and make {'readonly': [('state', 'not in', ['A', 'B'])]} all the other fields less object_name

Comment: @AlejandroGranados That's what I specified in my post and want to avoid. Those views are pretty big and inherited accross the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment of @EasyOdoo below, this seems not possible without redefining attributes of the `one2many` field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be possible.

For your simple example you even don't need `XPath` syntax:

```xml
<field name="object_ids" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': 0}</attribute>
</field>
```

This sets readonly to false. But if you want to remove the `attrs` attribute, because it's not needed anymore:

```xml
<field name="object_ids" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs" />
</field>
```

And the first example with `XPath` (second is also possible):

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='object_ids'" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': 0}</attribute>
</field>
```

Comment: Sorry but maybe I wasn't clear enough, I don't want to remove the attribute on `object_ids` field, because I know I can do it with xpath, I want it to not be applied in one field defined inside it (i.e. `object_name`) as if I was overriding the attribute in the child fields.

Comment: Oh, have you tried just setting it to `readonly="0"` on that field?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I can see in the debug that there are no `readonly` attributes but I guess the root attribute applies nonethless.

Comment: Indeed. Problem is that the view where this field lies is inherited by other views that may also redefine the form view for some `one2many` fields, and I don't want to read the whole code and find these parts where I should also add attributes to every child field.

Comment: Yeah, i understand the problem, but have no solution for it :-/